# Trying to bind two different dropdownlist using viewdata

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Trying to bind two dropdownlist from controller to view in the given below step but getting the error:

> "Unable to cast object of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Smart.Models.shift_details]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]'."

Any idea how to resolve it will be appreciated.

Model Class:

```
public class shift_details
        {
            public int ShiftId { get; set; }
            public string ShiftVal { get; set; }
        }
        public class Flag_details
        {
            public int FlagId { get; set; }
            public string FlagVal { get; set; }
        }
```

Controller:

```
public class Scm_Mod_SugController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Scm_Mod_Sug
        public ActionResult Index_shift()
        {
            ViewData["shift_details"] = Getshift_details();
            ViewData["Flag_details"] = GetFlag_details();
            return View();
        }
        private List<shift_details> Getshift_details()
        {
            List<shift_details> shift_detail = new List<shift_details>();
            shift_detail.Add(new shift_details { ShiftId = 0, ShiftVal = "Select" });
            shift_detail.Add(new shift_details { ShiftId = 1, ShiftVal = "A" });
            shift_detail.Add(new shift_details { ShiftId = 2, ShiftVal = "B" });
            shift_detail.Add(new shift_details { ShiftId = 3, ShiftVal = "C" });
            shift_detail.Add(new shift_details { ShiftId = 4, ShiftVal = "G" });
            return shift_detail;
        }
        private List<Flag_details> GetFlag_details()
        {
            List<Flag_details> flag_detail = new List<Flag_details>();
            flag_detail.Add(new Flag_details { FlagId = 0, FlagVal = "Select" });
            flag_detail.Add(new Flag_details { FlagId = 1, FlagVal = "N" });
            flag_detail.Add(new Flag_details { FlagId = 2, FlagVal = "P" });
            flag_detail.Add(new Flag_details { FlagId = 3, FlagVal = "R" });
            flag_detail.Add(new Flag_details { FlagId = 4, FlagVal = "W" });
            return flag_detail;
        }
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedEmployee",new SelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewData["shift_details"]), "ShiftId", "ShiftVal")
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedEmploe", new SelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Flag_details"]), "FlagId", "FlagVal")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ViewData` you won't need `@Html.DropDownList`. Use `SelectList`

```
<select asp-for="PropertyName" asp-items="ViewBag.shift_details"></select>
```

In controller

```
ViewData["shift_details"] = new SelectList(GetShift_details(), "ShiftId", "ShiftVal");
```

For both lists add the `ViewData` in the controller and a `select` tag in the view

Comment: but value is not binding in dropdown and is asp-for  and asp-items can be used in Mvc razor syntax

Answer (score 0):

I prefer creating the `SelectList` in the controller. Example below.

```
    public ActionResult Index_shift()
    {
        ViewData["shift_details"] = new SelectList(Getshift_details(), "ShiftId", "ShiftVal");
        ViewData["Flag_details"] = new SelectList(GetFlag_details(), "FlagId", "FlagVal");
        return View();
    }
```

And in the view you would use this.

```
            <select asp-for="ShiftId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.shift_details">
            </select>
            <select asp-for="FlagId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Flag_details">
            </select>
```

Comment: but value is not binding in dropdown and is asp-for  and asp-items can be used in Mvc view razor syntax

Answer (score 0):

To address your error. Change the return types of your private methods returning Lists to return a matching IEnumerable type instead

`private IEnumerable<shift_details> Getshift_details() { ... return shift_detail.ToArray(); }`